# Office add-in can't be installed on dekstop

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, office365, office-addins

so I tried to install this outlook add-in from GitHub https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-save-attachments. I already successfully install this add-in on my outlook web. So I notice on the manifest.xml the source location is like this `https://_SharePointTenantUrl_/_layouts/15/outlookhostedapp.aspx?componentId=04634d50-d72c-45ec-81d0-7b1f803800da`. First I thought is not working on the desktop because it can't read the *SharePointTenantUrl* so I change that to my SharePoint address. but when I install it the app still not shows up on my outlook desktop.
This is the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>04634d50-d72c-45ec-81d0-7b1f803800da</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>SPFx Provider</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Save Attachments"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="An SPFx Outlook addin that lets users copy email attachments to OneDrive folders."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://cdn.graph.office.net/prod/media/shared/addin-icon.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://cdn.graph.office.net/prod/media/shared/addin-icon.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4321/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.windows.net</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.4" />
      <Set Name="SharePointHostedAddin" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://_SharePointTenantUrl_/_layouts/15/outlookhostedapp.aspx?componentId=04634d50-d72c-45ec-81d0-7b1f803800da"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://cdn.graph.office.net/prod/media/shared/addin-icon.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://cdn.graph.office.net/prod/media/shared/addin-icon.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://cdn.graph.office.net/prod/media/shared/addin-icon.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://_SharePointTenantUrl_/_layouts/15/outlookhostedapp.aspx?componentId=04634d50-d72c-45ec-81d0-7b1f803800da" />
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-in groupLabel"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens taskpane."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo is for SPFx web parts, which must be installed in the SharePoint app catalog.

> This repository contains community samples that demonstrate different
> usage patterns for the SharePoint Framework client-side web parts.
>
> [...]
>
> SharePoint client-side web parts are controls that appear inside a
> SharePoint page but run locally in the browser. They're the building
> blocks of pages that appear on a SharePoint site.

Your SharePoint administrator can help you set up an app catalog for the tenant. If you are the SharePoint admin, you may want to refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-app-catalog

Comment: Hi, I already did that part.  but now the question is rather can I install it on outlook desktop or not. if not maybe is there any different approach to make the office add-in work on both desktop and web version? So the repo is SFPx web parts can I copy that and make it to the office add-in solution.

Comment: These are web parts designed to run in a SharePoint page, not a desktop app.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying this, I decided to create a new office add-in using the template from github.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/choose-patterns-for-developing-and-hosting-your-sharepoint-add-in for more information.

Comment: And note that SharePoint hosted apps and SPFx solutions published via the SharePoint App Catalog are not the same.